# how check overfitting on point pattern on a linear network using spatstat

Tags: r, spatstat, overfitting-underfitting

I have been using *lppm* (point pattern on a linear network) on *spatstat* with bunch of covariates and fitting a log-linear model but I couldn't see how to check over-fitting. Is there a quick way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want.

What tool would you use to check overfitting in (say) a linear model?

To identify whether individual observations may have been over-fitted, you could use `influence.lppm` (from the `spatstat.linnet` package).

To identify collinearity in the covariates, currently we do not provide a dedicated function in `spatstat`, but you could use the following trick. If `fit` is your fitted model of class `lppm`, first extract the corresponding GLM using

```
g <- getglmfit(as.ppm(fit))
```

Next install the package `faraway` and use the `vif` function to calculate the variance inflation factors

```
library(faraway)
vif(g)
```

Comment: How about instead of individual covariates check, is there code for the goodness of fit for the model?

Comment: See Chapter 11 of [the spatstat book](http://book.spatstat.org) for goodness-of-fit tests and model diagnostics. The functions described in the chapter are generic and can be applied to models on a network.

Comment: is it normal to have a negative McFadden's Pseudo-Rsquared value for lppm? How can I interpret it? according to [McFadden's Pseudo-2 Interpretation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82105/mcfaddens-pseudo-r2-interpretation) it is good to be around 0.2-0.4 but it does not say anything about being negative.